# Wordpress Create Upload Media Pop-up

Tags: wordpress, plugins, media

I'm trying to create a custom post type in wordpress, and one of things I need to do there is create a custom section that handles images for that post.

I want to create a button that will allow the user upload new images, and act exactly like the button in the editor's toolbar (right above the editor there is "Upload/Insert" and four little icons with "Add an Image", "Add Video", "Add Audio", "Add Media"), what I basically want is those four buttons outside of the editor.

Anyone got an easy fix for that, or maybe some workaround to achieve the same functionality?

Answer (score 0):

those buttons use media-upload.php in /wp-admin/

structured like so:

http://www.mysite.com/wp-admin/media-upload.php?post_id=123&type=image

with get_the_id() i reckon you should be able to generate similar links in your custom type.